# iPhone SDK - <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported color space

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was able to find a method to help me modify the alpha value for a pixel in a UIImage in my app, but I am running into two errors (the second is most certainly caused by the first). I can't, however, figure out what is going on.

My method:

```
- (void)modifyAlpha:(int)x and:(int)y {

    CGContextRef ctx; 
    CGImageRef imageRef = [scratchOffImage CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
    int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * y) + x * bytesPerPixel;

    rawData[byteIndex+3] = (char) (255); //Change the pixel value
    ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,  
                                CGImageGetWidth( imageRef ),  
                                CGImageGetHeight( imageRef ),  
                                8,  
                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow( imageRef ),  
                                CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef ),  
                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst ); //This line causes an error: incorrect colorspace

    imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);  
    UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];  

    CGContextRelease(ctx);  

    scratchOffImage = rawImage;  
    [scratchOffImageView setImage:scratchOffImage];

    free(rawData);

}
```

The error:

```
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported color space.
```

is being thrown on the line:

```
ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,  ...
```

and then the second error:

```
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0
```

is being thrown on the line:

```
imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);
```

My image is included in the bundle I originally made it by outputting it Photoshop's Save for Web function using PNG-8 with transparancy as the format.

When I ran the sample code that the function was first used in, the sample image worked fine. However, my image doesn't. How can I debug this?

**Does anyone have any idea how I can debug this? Might my input PNG be formatted incorrectly? How can I check this?**

Cheers,
Brett

EDIT 1: The original source code came from the example found [here](http://brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage/). The sample shows a conversion to greyscale, whereas I only need to change the alpha value.

EDIT 2: I have tried saving my image as a PNG-8 and a PNG-24, both with no luck.

Comment: Are CGImageGetWidth(imageRef); and CGImageGetHeight(imageRef); returning valid values for your image if you stop in the debugger just after they're set?

Comment: @Joachim: They are indeed. That was one of the first things I checked. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A PNG-8 uses an 8-bit indexed color space.  Quartz doesn't support indexed color spaces for `CGBitmapContext`.  The [`CGBitmapContextCreate` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000947-CH1g-SW1) says "Note that indexed color spaces are not supported for bitmap graphics contexts."

Instead of passing `CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef )` as the color space in your second call to `CGBitmapContextCreate`, you want to pass the same color space you used in your first call (your `colorSpace` variable).

**Anyway**, there's no reason to even create a second `CGBitmapContext`.  And you're leaking the result of `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`.  Just do this:

```
- (void)modifyAlpha:(int)x and:(int)y {

    CGImageRef imageRef = [scratchOffImage CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
    int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * y) + x * bytesPerPixel;

    rawData[byteIndex+3] = (char) (255); //Change the pixel value
    imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (context);  
    CGContextRelease(context);  

    UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];  

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    scratchOffImage = rawImage;  
    [scratchOffImageView setImage:scratchOffImage];

    free(rawData);

}
```